# String functions from programming pearls

Tags: c++

Here are functions on strings from programming pearls.

```
int wordncmp(char *p, char* q)
{   int n = k;
    for ( ; *p == *q; p++, q++)
        if (*p == 0 && --n == 0)
            return 0;
    return *p - *q;
}

int sortcmp(char **p, char **q)
{   return wordncmp(*p, *q);
}

char *skip(char *p, int n)
{   for ( ; n > 0; p++)
        if (*p == 0)
            n--;
    return p;
}
```

I don't understand what does sortcmp() do?  And does skip function return non null terminated part from char *p or what?
Please explain.

Comment: In wordncmp(), int n is initialized to an unknown variable or constant k. That needs an explanation.

Comment: These functions - as they stand - are junk. Are you sure you've copied them correctly? As Johan says, what is `k`? Also the `skip` function is nonsensical and cannot work, it always goes to the terminating character of p. The `n--` statement does nothing in that position.

Comment: @davit-datuashvili: Would you mind editing your question and changing `n=k=2` instead of just posting it as a comment? A little thought for future readers please?

Comment: @Binary: by the look of it, the functions expect a sequence of zero-separated "words", rather than a single zero-terminated string. Unconventional, but not completely nonsensical.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Thanks, it's been a while since I laboured under the yoke of C. Looks like nonsense until one is reminded of the insanity one regularly engaged in when handling strings in C. I can remember getting very - ahem - creative. Give me `var strings = new List<string>()` any day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complete guesswork, since I don't have a copy of the book, but it looks like these functions are for working with an unconventional string format consisting of a sequence of "words" separated by null characters.

- `wordncmp()` compares the first `k` words, where `k` is presumably a global variable to be set before calling the function.
- `sortcmp()` takes pointers to string pointers, and is presumably intended as the comparator when sorting an array of string pointers using `qsort()`.
- `skip()` skips over `n` words in a string.

In C++, you'd be better off using the standard String and Algorithms libraries to do this sort of thing; there's rarely a good reason to mess around with pointers and unconventional string representations.

Comment: The kernel returns "packed arrays" of strings like this in some syscalls, especially ones that are "ugly" like ioctl/sysctl. AIX particularly likes this sort of format. The end is double-null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

sortcmp takes double pointers (char**) as arguments, wordncmp does not. So sortcmp is a way of calling wordncmp with double pointers (char**). Its like a overload function.

skip does what you wrote:

> skip function return non null
>   terminated part from char *p

Answer (score 0):

I guess `sortcmp()` returns 0 if the in parameters `p` and `q` are equal, or a positive value if `p` is less than `q` or a negative value if `p` is greater than `q`. That is a useful functions when implementing a sort algorithm.